# Why is an audio compressed in FLAC(Free Lossless Audio Codec) changing its bit rate?

Tags: audio, sampling, mp3

I just recognized that the bit rate of an audio file compressed in FLAC is changing during play. On the other hand, MP3 file has a fixed bit rate such as 128, 192, 320kbsp etc. But why FLAC is not? Thank you for your time.

Comment: MP3 can also do variable bit rates. Variable bit rates improve compression, because they use less bits when the signal is not changing much.

Comment: and to add to @MBaz, with lossless coding, the bit rate **solely** depends on the audio content.  with lossy coding, you can have changing audio content and a constant bit rate if you're willing to put up with changing audio quality.